# Updating gameobject/character from blender to unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender

So i have object (character) imported in unity from blender and i updated something on it (added more animations) but now problem is how to update that in unity. I tried dragging only that animation from character to character inside project files but it is not working.

How could i do it?

If need more info tell me what to post.

Comment: This is just one disadvantage of using blender with Unity. You can't do that. You can do it with Maya but not with blender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you make modifications to a .blend file you need to export it as .fbx. While you are testing, I suggest using .blend files since you don't need to export every time, and when you are happy with the result switch to .fbx.
Just remove the old .fbx file from the Unity Editor and replace it with the newest one you exported. Use only the Editor to upload assets.

Comment: After adding the new animations did you reexport a new .fbx? Only .blend files update.

Comment: Something came to my mind, what do you mean by reexport. I did it to `mydocuments` (where was the first one) and overwrite it, and then tried to import it to the project, but what i didn't try is to overwrite it directly to the project files. Will that solve to problem?

Comment: Every time you make modifications to a .blend file you need to export it as .fbx. While you are testing, I suggest using .blend files since you don't need to export every time, and when you are happy with the result switch to .fbx.

Comment: Just remove the old .fbx file from the Unity Editor and replace it with the newest one you exported. Use only the Editor to upload assets.

Comment: Problem is that character will need to be changed a lot (since new spells = new animations). Also i do not quiet get you since on that object in my scene i have a lot of scripts and setting attached to, how could i switch only model and not affect everything else.

Comment: I have done it. It is working in one way > it updated my character, added new animations, kept everything inside scene but everything is shuffled. Now when i press W (need to go forward and start animation for walk) it start animation for spell5... I will try to figure out what is  going on

Comment: Ok i found it out. Animator has confused for some reason and shuffled animations of states so i just assigned animations to right states and it is working now. Thanks. Edit your answer so i can mark it as solution.

Comment: Thanks! I suggest you keep backups just in case you mess up something. I do it all the time.

Comment: Yea i do. Save .blend to the my documents, and .fbx to my project folder

Answer (score 1):

You can override the asset file by saving or exporting the file over the current file. If it doesn't show try refreshing the asset by right clicking it in unity.

Another way is to re-import an asset by right clicking the asset in unity and selecting a new asset to replace it with, such as a updated version of the asset you have made.

If you have done this but still cant see your animations, select the asset click the animations tab and press the + button on the clips box which might show you missing clips/animations

Comment: I tried exporting and overwriting it directly to the asset folder (where my character is in unity), but when i do it inside blender it doesn't ask me if i want to overwrite like everywhere else, it just close the window like the save was complete but in unity when i go `right click>refresh` and` right click>reimport` nothing happens. How to try second method since i can't see any command in unity that allows me to select new asset to replace it with.

Comment: Blender doesn't warn you that your overriding a file, so if when you press save/export it closes that should mean it has saved over it.

Comment: If you have tried refreshing and re-importing I would suggest saving the file in unity as a different name to check if they are getting imported. 

If they aren't which I feel might be the case, it might be just to do with the animations. Try the adding of clips. Just to clerify to do this. Click on the asset in unity. In the inspector window, you will see model, rig animation tabs. click animation and then click the + symbol on the bottom of the "clips box". does this show any other of your animations?

Comment: Covor Sorin's answer was solution. I deleted character from project files (i was scared to do it because i thought i will lose everything inside scene) and then imported it again. I had little problem because animator got confused and shuffled animations, but after little reassigning it is working now. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

You could try reimporting the Blender file.

Comment: by reimporting what you think? If you mean right click and then `reimport` it is not working (root folder and name are same, i overwrited it from blender). I do not know what will happen if i delete it from project files and then import. I am scared to lose all scripts setup inside scene